# Advantages and disadvantages of using multiple dispatcher servlets in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I just found out that you can have **multiple** `dispatcher-servlets` in a spring application. I would like to know if there are any advantages of taking this approach rather than traditional spring approach having **single** `dispatcher-servlet` for all the incoming requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Doc

> A web application can define any number of DispatcherServlets. Each servlet will operate in its own namespace, loading its own application context with mappings, handlers, etc. Only the root application context as loaded by ContextLoaderListener, if any, will be shared.

### Advantages of multiple dispatcher servlets  <sup><sub>OR</sub></sup>  Why we need multiple dispatcher servlets?

*Simple answer is to have [DispatcherServlet's](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) functionality in several forms*

### Dispatcher servlet functionality

---

- Dispatcher Servlet uses [HandlerMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) implementation to control the routing of requests to handler objects. Default is [BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html) and [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html).
- It's view resolution strategy can be specified via a [ViewResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) implementation, resolving symbolic view names into View objects. Default is [InternalResourceViewResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html).
- It's exception resolution strategy can be specified via a [HandlerExceptionResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html), for example mapping certain exceptions to error pages.
- It's strategy for resolving multipart requests is determined by a [MultipartResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html) implementation.
- It's locale resolution strategy is determined by a [LocaleResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html).
- It's theme resolution strategy is determined by a [ThemeResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ThemeResolver.html).

---

I will try to explain some of the functionalities provided by `DispatcherServlet`

**Declaring Multiple dispatcher servlets**
Consider we have two dispatcher servlets(DS) where DS1, DS2 are configured with different url patterns(`**.simple, **.beanName`) and they uses different dispatcher servlet configuration provided as given below.

```xml
DispatcherServlet     - simpleUrlHandlerDispatcherServlet
contextConfigLocation - /WEB-INF/simpleUrlHandlerMapping.xml
<url-pattern>*.simple</url-pattern>

DispatcherServlet     - beanNameUrlHandlerDispatcherServlet
contextConfigLocation - /WEB-INF/beanNameUrlHandlerMapping.xml
<url-pattern>*.beanName</url-pattern>
```

**<sup><sub>Advantage 1:</sub></sup> We can have different HandlerMapping for different set of URL**

*DS1 bean name url handler mapping configuration*

```xml
<bean name="/hello.beanName" class="com.pvn.mvc.HelloController" />
<bean name="/hi.beanName" class="com.pvn.mvc.HiController" />
```

*DS2 simple url handler mapping configuration*

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/hello.simple">simpleHello</prop>
            <prop key="/hi.simple">simpleHi</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**<sup><sub>Advantage 2:</sub></sup> We can have different view resolver for different set of URL's.**

**InternalResourceViewResolver** for DS1
where it deals with only `prefix + returned String + suffix`.
**[TilesViewResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles3/TilesViewResolver.html)** for DS2
its implementation provided by apache tiles which is a layout/skeleton based plugin high level functionality as given below.
[image]
Or if we use TilesViewResolver with different layout for different set of URL's
anonymous user - different layout
logged in user - different layout

**<sup><sub>Advantage 3:</sub></sup> We can have different theme resolver for different set of URL's.**
These resolver continuously monitors cookie/session to resolve theme and serves stylesheet/theme qualified (as given in below image). Below given just an example for outcome of [CookieThemeResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/theme/CookieThemeResolver.html).
Note: This is not about theme configuration but about theme resolver configuration.

[image]

**<sup><sub>Advantage 4:</sub></sup> We can have different locale resolver for different set of URL's.**
These resolver continuously monitors cookie/session/accept-header to resolve locale and loads application message qualified(as given in below image). Below given just an example for outcome of [CookieLocaleResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/CookieLocaleResolver.html).
Note: This is not about locale configuration but about locale resolver configuration.
[image]

Comment: Gives a good idea but all of these functionalities are achievable without using multiple servlets, a single dispatcher servlet with different controllers can do it.

Comment: No you can't. Dispatcher servlet supports only one configuration for each functionality. Will you please explain how we can have multiple view resolver with one dispatcher servlet configured? how we can have multiple locale resolver with one dispatcher servlet configured? how we can have multiple theme resolver with one dispatcher servlet configured? Even it applies for handlerMapping.